# Using a oracle data adapter to deploy and fill reports on jasperserver

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I have a oracle dataadapter that is a datasource on jasperserver.
But when I create a report using this adapter, it does not preview or fill the report on Jaspersoft Studio and JasperReports Server. Is there anyway I can create a new oracle dataadapter for testing purposes. I have downloaded `odjc7.jar`. But when I create a driver path to this file. I recieve a error `Reason:java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Unknown host specified`

Any details to whether oracle datasource can fill reports would be much appreciated and any details to creating a new oracle dataadapter.

Comment: Where did you get this error? At Server or at Studio?

Comment: Seems that the jdbc connection string is wrong. Did you check this string via Java code or at some Oracle client?

Comment: I received the error on studio, I used the same string that is working on the other oracle adapter. See I do have a working adapter but it does not fill reports and I wanted to create a new one to see what the reason could be.

Comment: The working adapter is in use on another pc and jasper tools respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If your link is correct and already works on other pcs/servers, then the error is in the connection to the database.

- Check your connection to the database. Open a SQL-Developer tool and try to connect  to the database.
- Check if you really did add the driver to the data adapter:
  It should look like this:

[image]

[image]

If you didn't provide the right driver it will not work!

- Recheck your ojdbc7.jar. Maybe download it again from an official source. Also sometimes the ojdbc7.jar leads to some unknown errors. At a Jaspersoft Roadshow they recommended to still use the ojdbc6.jar.